# Upload images into database with PHP

Tags: php, oop, pdo

I am currently trying to make a function to upload images into the database with php. at the moment you can upload the images and they will be placed in a folder named images. This works fine, however now I am trying to get this into the database, and for some reason, my function is not working :(

**Upload.php**

```
    <form action="upload.php" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data">
    <h2>Select Image:</h2><input type="file" name="image"> <br/>
        <input type="submit" name="upload" Value="Upload now"><br/>

    <?php
   $saveImage = $user->saveImage($name,$image_name);
    if(isset($_POST['upload'])){
    $image_name = $_FILES['image'] ['name'];
    $image_type = $_FILES['image'] ['type'];
    $image_size = $_FILES['image'] ['size'];
    $image_tmp_name = $_FILES['image'] ['tmp_name'];
    saveImage($name,$image_name);

        if($image_name==''){
            echo "<script>alert('Please Select a file')</script>";
            exit();
        }

        else {
        move_uploaded_file($image_tmp_name, "images/$image_name");
        echo "<p>Image uploaded succesfully</p><br/>";
        echo "<img src='images/$image_name'>";
        }
    }
    ?>
```

**class.user.php**

```
public function saveImage($name,$image_name){
$stmt = $this->db->prepare("INSERT INTO images(image_name,image_image) 
                                                       VALUES(:name, :image_name)");

    $stmt->bindparam(":name", $name);
    $stmt->bindparam(":image_name", $image_name);                                 
    $stmt->execute();   
    return $stmt;   
}
```

I am trying to build a custom CMS, to learn about OOP as I am quite new in Object-oriented programming and I find it quite difficult. Maybe you can see something wrong here?

**Errors:**

> Notice: Undefined variable: name in /Applications/MAMP/htdocs/test/upload.php on line 83
>
> Notice: Undefined variable: image_name in /Applications/MAMP/htdocs/test/upload.php on line 83
>
> Fatal error: Uncaught exception 'PDOException' with message 'SQLSTATE[23000]: Integrity constraint violation: 1048 Column 'image_name' cannot be null' in /Applications/MAMP/htdocs/test/class.user.php:148 Stack trace: #0 /Applications/MAMP/htdocs/test/class.user.php(148): PDOStatement->execute() #1 /Applications/MAMP/htdocs/test/upload.php(83): USER->saveImage(NULL, NULL) #2 {main} thrown in /Applications/MAMP/htdocs/test/class.user.php on line 148

Comment: 'not working' is not something that can be used to help you. what's going wrong? any error message? if you make a test on a different server you get the very same behaviour? which rdbms are you using?

Comment: add the relevant information in the initial post. error messages in the comments are difficult to read.

Comment: why do you need to save the images in database (there may be a different method for you)? storing them in folders is a good method.

Comment: @machineaddict She/he is storing them in a folder. I'm assuming that just the paths are stored into the db.

Comment: ^ yes Andrew, exactly!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Basicly `image_name` is null, which is not allowed by your DB constraints.

Well, `$name` is never set, which in turn violates the DB constraint of image_name NOT NULL.

Comment: when I upload a file, the input should not be null right?

Comment: I see, when I change it to $user->saveImage($image_name,$image_name); it is indeed inserting into database, not exactly how I want it to do, but I think I can figure out the rest

Answer (score 0):

```
$saveImage = $user->saveImage($name,$image_name);
```

Remove this line to your code

Comment: Gives me the error: Fatal error: Call to undefined function saveImage() in /Applications/MAMP/htdocs/test/upload.php on line 88

Comment: I see, when I change it to $user->saveImage($image_name,$image_name); it is indeed inserting into database, not exactly how I want it to do, but I think I can figure out the rest

Comment: add this $user->saveImage($name,$image_name); for saveImage($name,$image_name);